# Support Multiple Active Directory Domains

Tags: sharepoint-server

Currently my SharePoint is installed in `ABC` domain and I am able to add users and manage permissions for `ABC` domain.
But, now I need to provide access to another domain say `XYZ` but unable to add users in `XYZ` domain.

Please let us know what is the steps required to configure to support my SharePoint portal from users of two different domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get this done , first we need to configure the people picker to search the users from both the domains ,

execute the below power shell commands from SharePoint server machine to configure the people picker :

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:DomainA.com;forest:DomainB.com,DomainB\login,password" -url "Your webapp url"
```

refer below articles for more info :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(office.12).aspx

before configuring the people picker the second domain needed to be added as a Trusted domain so that we can grant access to the users from other domain as well .

we need to go through some specific configuration for this which is clearly explained in this [Article](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-add-trust-domains-in-a-sharepoint-farm/)

Comment: what is the value to be put for DomainB\login,password"  login,password. Is it the domain b user's id and password.

Comment: that is a credentials which can authenticate and read the users from the Domain B , you need to register this credentials if you have one way trust between the domains if you have two way trust then no need to specify the credentials . refer this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Can you share a article on how to maintain two way trust

Comment: the link is shared in the answer above